# нужно установить библиотеки типа numpy и др. используя pip install

Tags: python, pip, install

Я установил Python 3.9 64-bit version и мне нужно добавить разные библиотеки. Я так понимаю у меня проблема с path. Если ввести в панели

> C:\Users\пк>pip install numpy
> выходит

> "pip" не является внутренней или внешней командой, исполняемой
> программой или пакетным файлом.

Не понимаю, как это можно решить. Пожалуйста подскажите.

Comment: `python -m pip install numpy`. Но лучше установить Python по-человечески вместе с пакетным менеджером.

Comment: с пакетным менеджером это который?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В Windows похоже нужно запускать "py -m pip". 
Попробуйте: `py -m pip install numpy.`

Если не сработатет: 
С достаточно новым питоном pip по идее [не нужно устанавливать отдельно](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/). 
Проверить наличие pip: `py -m pip --version` 
Если нет, то попробуйте установить через [ensurepip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ensurepip.html): `python -m ensurepip --upgrade`

Comment: частично сработало! `Successfully installed numpy-1.19.4` только появилось предупреждение `WARNING: The script f2py.exe is installed in 'C:\Users\пк\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.` что можно сделать, чтобы связать с PATH?

Answer (score 0):

1. Переустановите питон имхо самый простой вариант.
2. Вариант сложнее добавить pip в переменную path.
   Pip находится в директории c python в папке Scripts, ее нам и надо добавить в Path.
   Далее жмем пуск - Параметры - О программе - Дополнительные параметры системы (столбец справа) - Переменные среды - находим Path и жмем кнопку изменить - добавляем путь к папке Scripts.
   В моем случае это `C:\Python\Python38\Scripts`. Путь зависит от установки питона.

Comment: а Параметры где я могу найти?

Comment: Если win 10 то нажать пуск и там сбоку шестеренка, как наведете курсор будет подпись параметры.

Comment: Если win7 то можно по "мой компьютер" ПКМ - Свойства. Там сбоку должны быть доп параметры.  Или через панель управления - система. К сожалению win7 нет перед глазами.